# How to change your public profile name in AliExpress

Tags: aliexpress

I cannot find any piece of information about it in the AliExpress [help pages](http://aliexpress.com) or anywhere else online. Assume you use your real name in name section. There is no alias possibility. One option is then use fake name in name section of the profile.

Now, they use the strategy to show user's first digit in first name and last name like `M*** M.` where first name `Masi` and lastname `Masi`.

They do not have any contact form to contact them so I cannot get this further. 
Now, I use a nick name in profile's name field, but then, keep correct details in shipping address when shopping.

---

How can you change the public profile name in AliExpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed their policy. Now, you can change the public name.

Answer (score -1):

Well there is no option, weird how people can have usernames with multiple words if it just takes the email account minus @emailservice.extension because I can't change it
Maybe you need the app and it's an app exclusive feature